# Sorting a single field by both numeric and dictionary in unix?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I need to sort a file with names like these:

```
UN1
UN12
UR1
UR21
UN4
UN5
```

I tried using `sort -n` and `sort -h`, but these don't work. I want the output to be:

```
UN1
UN4
UN5
UN12
UR1
UR21
```

Importantly, I can't assume anything about the names in the list ahead of time, so I can't cut the first two characters off into one column, and the trailing number in another to handle them differently.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/natural-sort-with-just-bash-or-core-linux-commands-507796/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page

> -V, --version-sort
>                 natural sort of (version) numbers within text

`sort -V` produces :

```
UN1
UN4
UN5
UN12
UR1
UR21
```

Seems like what you want.

**Edit**

From the comments : `Note that -V is a gnu extension`.

Comment: Note that `-V` is a gnu extension.

Answer (score 0):

My sort doesn't have `-V` :-(

Some line noise:

```
perl -E 'say sort {($a =~ s/\d+//r) cmp ($b =~ s/\d+//r) or ($a =~ s/\D+//r) <=> ($b =~ s/\D+//r)} <>'
```

timtowdi &c.